# What's the difference between "virtualenv" and "-m venv" in creating Python Virtual environments

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

Sorry if I sound a bit foolish.
I'm confused about this:
What's the difference between the two:

```
virtualenv myvenv
```

and

```
-m venv myvenv
```

The first one works well for me in creating virtual environments while the other does not.

I `cd` into my development directory and use `virtualenv myvenv` and it creates the virtual environment. But if I use `-m venv myvenv`, it just gives errors.

Comment: You would need to use `python -m venv myvenv` for that to work..., where `python -m` calls the `venv` module as a script and passes `myvenv` as an argument to that script.

Comment: This question is misleading because it is presented as if it were about the difference between two commands, but OP appears to have been **actually asking** why the second version, `-m venv myvenv`, **verbatim**, doesn't work at all. The reason it doesn't work at all is because it is **not a valid command**; it should say `python -m venv myvenv` instead.

Comment: "But if I use -m venv myvenv, it just gives errors." - this is a **textbook** example of why questions that lack debugging details should be closed immediately. "What errors?" would have immediately cleared up the confusion. Instead, we get a poorly-asked version of a "canonical" (that is still not great; "what's the difference" questions are normally two smaller questions in a trenchcoat).

Comment: ... Actually, even overlooking that, it wouldn't be a canonical for the "what's the difference" question; we already have [What is the difference between venv, pyvenv, pyenv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**venv** is a package shipped directly with python 3. So you don't need to `pip install` anything.

**virtualenv** instead is an independent library available at https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/ and can be installed with `pip`.

They solve the same problem and work in a very similar manner.

If you use python3 I suggest to avoid any "extra" dependencies and just stick with `venv`.

Your error is probably because you use Python2/pip2.

Comment: Thank you for this. If I delete my current python installation and reinstall Python 3.5 on my PC will it solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, probably, but if you give me the specific error I can tell you more precisely. However if you prefer to use python2 you can just use `virtualenv` which is pretty much identical to `venv`

Comment: Thanks. I was missing "python" before the "-m  venv". Now I understand the difference.

Answer (score 59):

I think the [virtualenv docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) explain this the best:

`venv` is a subset of `virtualenv` integrated into the standard library since Python 3.3. The subset meaning that only part of `virtualenv`s functionality is in `venv`:

- `venv` can be slower since it does not have the "`app-data` seed method". See more about virtualenv Seeders in the [docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/20.2.2/user_guide.html#seeders).
- `venv` can only be updated by upgrading the Python version,  while `virtualenv` is updated using pip.
- `venv` is not extendable
- `virtualenv` has richer [programmatic API](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#programmatic-api)   (describe virtual environments without creating them). See the [`venv` API here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#api).
- `venv` cannot automatically discover arbitrarily installed python versions, while `virtualenv` does. This means, that with `venv` you have to specify the full path of the `python` executable, if you want to use some other python version than the first one in the PATH. With `virtualenv`, you can just give the version number. See [python discovery](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#python-discovery) in the virtualenv documentation.

To me the differences are quite subtle and the only practical difference has been that `venv` is included in the standard library (since 3.3). I have been using `python -m venv venv` for a long time and have never needed an alternative.

Comment: Last part does feel like its not really valid? If i have x amount of python versions, i can still call any of those pythons directly with full paths and get a correct runtime paths for that particular interpreter. So, making a "venv" with that random python only requires that i know where that python is, say `~/localcopies/python/3.7.7/python -mvenv myproject`  ..

Comment: Yeah I agree. That was a bit misleadingly stated in the virtualenv docs. The difference is in the autodiscovery of python versions. I edited the answer.

Comment: I think `venv` is *always* slower, not just sometimes. The docs you linked to (thank you!) say anywhere from 10x to 10,000x slower. That sounds like a not very "subtle" difference. And that has been my experience on Linux. `virtualenv` saves us tons of CI-CD pipeline minutes in gitlab.