# remove virtual environment created with venv in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

How can I delete a virtual environement created with

```
python3 -m venv <name>
```

Can I just remove the directory?

This seems like a question googling should easily answer, but I only found answers for deleting environments created with `virtualenv` or `pyvenv`.

Comment: Yes, deleting the directory should be just fine. I have done it multiple times, and re-created them without any problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, delete the directory. it's where executables for the venv and modules and libraries and entire other stuff for venvs is kept.

Comment: delete _which_ directory?

Comment: The one containing your virtual environment. If you create one with `env my-env`, the directory to delete would be `my-env`

Comment: @gonczor But that's where my source lives.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman what do you mean? It's a place for libraries, not the code you've written. If you create a virtual env with `virtualenv venv`, then `venv` stores external dependencies, not your application code.

Comment: @gonczor That could've been more clear. Also that `python3 -m venv venv` [replaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe) `virtualenv` and other older methods.

Comment: @StingyJack for Ubuntu the directory is "/home/username/.local/bin/.virtualenvs". Go inside this folder and you will find the folder to be deleted. This folder has the same name of your virtual environment.

Answer (score 9):

If your environment is active, you should deactivate it first. Not sure if not deactivating will cause any problems, but that's the right way to do it. Once you deactivate, you can simply delete the virtual environment directory.

To deactivate an active environment, simply execute the 'deactivate' bash command.

Comment: Which directory? There are multiple.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman The directory doesn't matter. The environment is mentioned before the command prompt in brackets: (my_env_name). You can deactivate if you want to keep the terminal session running, you can also close all terminal sessions that are running the virtual environment.

Answer (score 7):

In your venv project folder created using `python3 -m venv .` or whatever, run this to remove the venv files:

```
rm -r bin include lib lib64 pyvenv.cfg share
```

If you're still in the venv by using `source bin/activate`, run `deactivate` first.

However, according to [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments), one should always use `python3 -m venv .venv` so the venv files are neatly contained in a single `.venv` folder in your project root. That way the Visual Studio Code Python extension can find/use it as well.

Answer (score 2):

To delete a environment in WINDOWS. Make sure you are in activated environment:

```
$ deactivate
```

This will deactivate your current environment. 
Now you can go to the directory where your  folder or  folder is present. Delete it manually. DONE!

To create a new environment , Simply from bash:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
```

To activate it:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: To deactivate on Windows from a normal command line, run `./venv/scripts/deactivate.bat`

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in way to remove a virtualenv created with `python3 -m venv <name>`. If you created a python3.6 virtualenv in, for instance, `/usr/local` then you can remove it with an Ansible playbook like:

```yaml
---
- name: Remove virtualenv
  hosts: all

  vars:
    venv: /usr/local

    virtualenv_files:
      - pyvenv.cfg
      - bin/activate
      - bin/activate.csh
      - bin/activate.fish
      - bin/easy_install
      - bin/easy_install-3.6
      - bin/pip
      - bin/pip3
      - bin/pip3.6
      - bin/python
      - bin/python3
      - bin/python3.6
      - bin/wheel
      - lib/python3.6/site-packages

  tasks:

  - name: Freeze virtualenv
    shell: |
      set -e
      source "{{ venv }}/bin/activate"
      pip3 freeze > /tmp/frozen
    args:
      creates: /tmp/frozen
    register: frozen
    failed_when: false

  - name: Remove site-packages from virtualenv
    when: frozen.rc == '0'
    become: true
    shell: |
      set -e
      source {{ venv }}/bin/activate
      pip3 uninstall -y -r /tmp/frozen

  - name: Remove virtualenv_files
    become: true
    file:
      path: "{{ venv }}/{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    loop: "{{ virtualenv_files }}"
```