# How to accesss a python virtual enviroment when the command prompt is accidentally closed?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I opened a virtual enviroment and accidentally closed the command prompt window in Windows.

I wanted to delete the virtual enviroment folder, but when I tried, it says program is running which still uses the files.

So how do I get back to the virtual enviroment, without opening a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Just kill the daemon-process by command in Ctrl+Alt+Del interface. Then you can delete a folder

Comment: How do I find the name of the process? I tried looking up the name of the virtual enviroment, but didn't find anything

Comment: Try kill the process with a name that looks like "python"

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any process with that name either

Comment: Seems like someone have same problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158676/remove-virtual-environment-created-with-venv-in-python3