# Python: How to determine which folders belong to which virtualenv manager?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv, virtualenvwrapper

Python has at least three ways to manage virtual environments:

1. `module venv`
2. `virtualenvwrapper`
3. Classic `virtualenv`

See [What is the difference between venv, pyvenv, pyenv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe) and [Python venv and virtualenvwrapper combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826517/python-venv-and-virtualenvwrapper-combined) for discussions of the differences.

Moreover, some (all?) of these can be installed in three ways:

1. `pip`
2. System package manager (e.g. `sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper`)
3. Directly from source

This leaves up to 9 different virtual environment managers in a single system, each using different folders and scripts.

How do we sort this out? In my system, for example, I see `~/.virtualenv` and `~/.virtualenvs`, and `activate.csh` in many places:

```
/snap/core18/2253/usr/lib/python3.6/venv/scripts/posix/activate.csh
/snap/core18/2284/usr/lib/python3.6/venv/scripts/posix/activate.csh
/snap/core20/1270/usr/lib/python3.8/venv/scripts/posix/activate.csh
/snap/core20/1328/usr/lib/python3.8/venv/scripts/posix/activate.csh
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/python3.6/venv/scripts/posix/activate.csh
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/python3.6/venv/scripts/posix/activate.csh
/usr/lib/python3.9/venv/scripts/posix/activate.csh
```

In addition, some projects can have their own virtual envs in the project folder.

How do we sort out which folder is managed by which virtualenv manager? Is there a way to consolidate all the different managers? In 2022, what's a clean, consolidated way to manage virtual environments: Do we still need `virtualenvwrapper`, and if so, which installation path and how do we consolidate to it?

Comment: "*How do we sort this out?*" Sorry, we don't.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1987/

Comment: "*In 2022, what's a clean, consolidated way to manage virtual environments…?*" None. Sad but true. Also you have forgotten `pyenv` and `conda`/`anaconda`/`miniconda`.

Comment: I use venv only and don't have any problem.