# "python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenv/miniprojects" vs "virtualenv venv -p python3"

Tags: python, virtualenv

What is the difference between these two commands `python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenv/miniprojects` and `virtualenv venv -p python3` and how will they impact my code. Consider that `virtualenv venv -p python3` in my mini projects directory.

Comment: both create virtual envs in different dirs. As much as I know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between venv, pyvenv, pyenv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe)