# How can I make venv install a python3.6 binary?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-venv, virtual-environment

When I run `python -m venv`, the virtual environment directory that `venv` creates includes a binary named `python` and another named `python3` which is just a link to `python`. (In my installation, `python` is Python 3.6 and `python2` is Python 2.7.)

My problem is, sometimes (and I can't understand what's the difference between subsequent invocations) it also creates another symlink `python3.6` pointing to `python`, but sometimes it doesn't. I need this symlink (actually, `tox` needs it). The binaries `pip3.6` and `easy_install-3.6` are always installed in the virtualenv.

Is there any way I can make sure that `python -m venv` creates a symlink `python3.6`?

(Disclaimer: I'm using pyenv to manage my Python installation, but I can reproduce the behavior above using `/usr/bin/python -m venv`)

Comment: Generally, I use "python3.6 -m venv myvenv". This distinguishes it from any other python 3.x I may have installed. Don't know if that address your issue, but maybe.

Comment: I am sure that the python version being used is 3.6, because it installs `pip3.6` and `easy_install-3.6`, but I'll try

Comment: It worked! Apparently, python uses the version number in the `$0` argument to decide what binary versions it will install. Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating venvs (`python -m venv`, not virtualenv), I've had success by including the version number in the call to create;

```
python3.6 -m venv myvenv
```

Comment: if `venv` has this issues.. what is the benefit of useing `venv` over `virtualenv`?

Comment: Also for completeness: [this search](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+tox) in [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv)'s github issues brings up [this solution](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/202#issuecomment-284728205), which I've found very satisfying: when creating the virtualenv with `pyenv virtualenv`, use the `-p` flag to specify which binary pyenv-virtualenv should use when calling `python -m venv`. The final, complete command will be something like `pyenv virtualenv -p python3.6 3.6.4 myvenv`.

Comment: @alpha_989; See the answer from Riaz in this SO question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the binary already available to get venv to use it, but if you have it, it shouldn't matter if you use `python2 -m venv` or `python3 -m venv`. If you want 3.6, try:

`` python -m venv python=`which python3.6` ~/envs/py36 ``