# What is the difference between `virtualenv -p python3` and `python3 -m venv`?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I see the following commands. But I am not sure about their differences. They seem both create virtual environment. Could anybody explain the differences? Thanks.

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between venv, pyvenv, pyenv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe)

Comment: `venv` is available in Python3.6+, and `virtualenv` needs to be externally installed. More info: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/15

Answer (score 2):

**basic breakdown**

`python3 -m venv` = "make me a virtual environment using Python3's built-in `venv` module"

`virtualenv -p python3` = "make me a virtual environment using the virtualenv package and [use the Python3 binary](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/) to do it"

**more**

a more comprehensive answer re: Python's various environmental tools found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe) (as mentioned in the comment on your question)