# ImportError: ./cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: undefined symbol: EVP_PKEY_get_id when using Cryptography

Tags: python, pip, cryptography, pycrypto, pyopenssl

I am developing a Python project that uses Cryptography and PyOpenSSL. I created a virtual environment for all the project's dependencies based on Python 3.10. Since I need some more OpenSSL functionality than what these libraries provide, I modified the libraries, then built them with `pip install -e .` (in the venv).
I then ran my project and it worked perfectly, including the new functionality I added to the libraries.
Now, I want to run the same project on a different device, so I pushed my project, as well as the Cryptography library and the PyOpenSSL library to three separate GitLab Repo and cloned them from my laptop. I included the venv folder in the Git Project, because I assumed that would make it easier to run on my second device.

I cloned the three projects and ran my project, however, I encountered the following error:

> ImportError: /home/xy/Projects/cryptography/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: undefined symbol: EVP_PKEY_get_id

I tried installing the two libraries again (from the cloned Git Projects), but the error persists.
I checked that OpenSSL is correctly installed with `openssl version` and it seems like it is.
I assume there is some problem with the venv, so I tried the same without a venv:
Installed the libraries, then ran the project, but the problem persists.

I assume this is not some problem with my Code, since it is running fine on my Desktop,
but rather a problem with pip installing the libraries.
Both devices run KDE Neon, Python 3.10.12 and OpenSSL 3.0.2.
Does someone have a fix for this? Does it make sense to share the venv via Git or should I create a new venv? Did I make any mistake when installing?

Edit: I tried using `virtualenv` instead of `venv` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66240707/9795530), but it still does not work.
Also, I figured that EVP_PKEY_get_id was added in OpenSSL 3.0. So I assume the problem is that I compile cryptography against OpenSSL 3.0 but then its linked against OpenSSL 1.x (as described [here](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4274)).
I am not sure how to fix this though. I noticed that in `/usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu` there are the following files

> libcrypt.so
> libcrypt.so.1
> libcrypt.so.1.1.0

and

> libssl.so
> libssl.so.1.1
> libssl.so.3

I wonder whether the 1.1 versions of these are used somehow and cause the problem? I am not sure how to check that though and I'm hesitant to just delete those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me:
The [Docs](https://cryptography.io/en/42.0.2/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux) provide a script to build a static wheel.
In my venv, I ran `pip uninstall cryptography`, then created an empty `.sh` file, pasted the script below in there and ran it. This created a `.whl` file, that I then installed with `pip install <.whl_file>`

Script (slightly modified for my local cryptography version and OpenSSL 3.0.2:

```
set -e

OPENSSL_VERSION="3.0.2"
CWD=$(pwd)

virtualenv env
. env/bin/activate
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U wheel pip
curl -O https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar xvf openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz
cd openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}
./config no-shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 -fPIC --prefix=${CWD}/openssl
make && make install
cd ..
OPENSSL_DIR="${CWD}/openssl" pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-binary cryptography ./
```