# How to create a python virtual environment from the command line?

Tags: python, command-line, virtualenv

What is the command to create a python virtual environment from the command line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+how+to+create

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Linux/macos: 
virtualenv -p python3 env 
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt

windows:
virtualenv -p python3 env
env\scripts\activate
pip install -r requirements.txt

if you need to specify the full path to python you can use something like virtualenv -p C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe myvirtualenv