# How to install xlrd in python3 library

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd, macos-mojave

I am trying to install xlrd to read Excel files in python.

I have tried this: pip install -U pip setuptools. My macOS Mojave 10.4.3 has Python 2.7 which is where the default install goes to. But I have also installed Python3.7. How do I get pip install to my 3.7 directory?

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install xlrd`?

Comment: I'm not on a mac so I'm assuming it's the same as linux.

Comment: Yeah. I tried pip3 install xlrd. But system says cannot find pip3. macOS is same as Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon the easiest/cleanest solution would be to use a tool that isolates your python environment, such as [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)

Once installed, create a virtual env by specifying which version of python you want to use:

`$> virtualenv -p python3 env`

Note: puttin `python3` directly works only for mac, with linux, you must specify the absolute path or your python binary.

And then 'activate' your environment:

`$> source env/bin/activate`

From here, any python or pip command you use will use python3.

`$> pip install xlrd`

Virtualenv has the advantage of not 'polluting' your local python installation, your can manage your pip modules installed more easily.

If you want more detail on how it works and the other alternatives, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe)

Comment: Thanks. I did that and installed xlrd 1.2.0. However when I do a pd.ExcelFile(<filename>) in jupyter I get a error: Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support

Comment: Check which version of `xlrd` has been installed by running `pip list | grep xlrd`. `pip` must have been using some cached version. Try to reinstall your pip modules with the `--no-cache-dir` option. I am not very familiar with Jupyter, so maybe the problem could come from somewhere else.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore on Catalina which uses zsh, any help in this regard?

Comment: @Nicholas `pip3 install xlrd` worked for me. I am using Mac-catalina 10.15.5 version

Answer (score 2):

I am on Mac machine(Catalina -version 10.15.5) and below pip3 command worked for me.

`pip3 install xlrd`

python version : 3.7.6

OS : Mac-Catalina(10.15.5)

Comment: did not work before now it works also for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Tapan Hegde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12105019/tapan-hegde), `pip3 install xlrd` worked from me, after installing the pip3, like this:

```
sudo apt update

apt install python3-pip

pip3 install xlrd
```

Answer (score 0):

When `pip install xlrd` not work and in computer is still old version, then try do it with current version, for example `pip install xlrd==2.0.1`.
The current versions are [here](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html)