# Migrating from virtualenv to venv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am/was a happy user of `virtualenv` for years. Switched to `Python 3` for all my projects a year a ago. `Python 3` has a command line switch to create/manage virtual environments like so:

`python3 venv my_virtualenv`

After reading this article [The definitive guide to setup my Python workspace](https://medium.com/@henriquebastos/the-definitive-guide-to-setup-my-python-workspace-628d68552e14), I would like to use `pyenv` to manage different installations of Python 3.x on my Mac in combination with `venv`.

From this article [1] I get that `pyenv-virtualenv` needs/uses `venv`.

I have a ton of virtual environments created in the past years with `virtualenv` in `$HOME/.virtualenvs`. Is there a way to "migrate" those virtual environments to `venv`? Or is there a way to define a `WORKON_HOME` folder for `venv`? I use/d this for `virtualenv` in my zsh config file:

`export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs`

---

[1] [What is the difference between venv, pyvenv, pyenv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe)

Comment: `pyenv` can simply get out of the way if you want to activate a traditional virtualenv. I don't see a particular need to migrate anything.