# venv equivalent to VirtualEnvironment().install()

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I want to dynamically create, destroy & use Python virtual environments that contain code loaded by `pip`.

The `virtualenvapi` Python package looks promising because it provides an `install()` method that uses `pip` to install packages. It supports both package name and URL arguments, both of which I need.

However, I would prefer to use `venv` as I don't care about Python earlier than 3.6, virtual environments are complex, `venv` is in the standard library but `virtualenvapi` isn't, and there are [good arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47559925) to prefer `venv`.

`venv` provides API support with [`venv.EnvBuilder()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#api). But how does one accomplish this with it:

```
env = VirtualEnvironment('/path/to/environment/name')
env.install('git+https://github.com/KarrLab/log.git#egg=log')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below **.py** may help your demand.

```
import virtualenv
import pip
import os

# create and activate the virtual environment
venv_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".venv")
virtualenv.create_environment(venv_dir)
execfile(os.path.join(venv_dir, "bin", "activate_this.py"))

# pip install a package using the venv as a prefix
pip.main(["install", "--prefix", venv_dir, "xmltodict"])
```

[Referance](http://jelly.codes/articles/python-virtualenv-from-within-python/)

**Edit 1:**

Also its including how to use pip with script.