# Who uses pyenv in their companies?

Tags: python, benchmarking, pyenv

Because of our company's policy of standardizing tools and for benchmarks purpose, as one of its requirements, we need to know which companies used pyenv as its main environment managers for python. We tried to use pyenv because we found some problems in regards to usage of anaconda (got broken packages, conflicted packages etc.) but we need some justifications to use pyenv as our standard environment management tools.

I'v been trying to search it on the internet but as far as I know I only got the stars of pyenv git (currently it is on 18.1K stars) and its active github page.

So, for that matter, Do any of uses pyenv as its main environment management tools? It will be nice if you also provide your company or a reason. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

In my team we decided to use pyenv instead of virtualenv. I am not saying that it's way easier or way different from virtualenv. Commands are not the same and it took a while to get used to them. The only con was that first you need to switch your local python version in pyenv in order to be able to create a new environment. Pros: very easy to create environments with different python versions (for example to test compatibility of your code with Python 3.6.x..3.8). Here is also a great answer and a comparison https://stackoverflow.com/a/41573588/12867241