# How to effectively get python modules working across different environments

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm a newbie to python and just trying to get my head wrapped around how to get things to run/work in python across different environments. What I mean in this context in regards to environment is this. I'm learning python on my MacBook pro - Catalina 10.15.5. I've installed python using `brew install`. I use `pyenv` to control versions. Through **iTerm** I would create virtual environments using `virtualenv` and `pip install` to install modules, etc.

I'm also using **Visual Studio Code** and **PyCharm** to learn and understand these tools as well.

I've reviewed and tried a number of python tutorials in my journey to learning python.
With that said, why is it when using **iTerm**, if I do a `pip install <module>`, the module shows being installed with no errors, but when running the application (`FLASK_APP=app.py flask run)`, i'll get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pynoob/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/pynoob/Desktop/MyWork/Learn/LearningPython/OktaTutorial/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_oidc'
```

However, when I run these same in Visual Studio Code, in the terminal, it works. How?
What am I misunderstanding fundamentally when using modules? Does it have to do with iTerm vs. Visual Studio Code?

Here's the snippet of python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, g, redirect, url_for
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
from okta import UsersClient
```

Comment: Check out [this post'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe?r=SearchResults&s=1|196.6315)

Comment: interesting article..now, i'm really confused on what to use. Too many options.

Comment: Thanks @C.Pappy - read that article and it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the article as shared in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C196.6315). I ran the following commands in iTerm and got it working:

```
 python3 -m venv <nameyourenv>
 pip install -r requirements.txt
 FLASK_APP=app.py flask run
```

Example output:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```