# No module named 'odf' due to wrong Python version

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have many different versions of Python, but a version that I use and that terminal show me if use command Python – version is 3.10.0.

When I use command pip list I got a big list of library, including the one I recently installed odfpy.

I open VsCode, choose Python version 3.10.0 and try to import odf but...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odf'

For sure I need to set something on VsCode or change some configuration in Linux but I cannot find a normal explanation of how to solve this issue.

If I change the Python version in VsCode with 3.8.10, odfpy (and also Django just installed) is recognized. So I suppose that, even if the Python version selected on the terminal is 3.10.0, when I pip install something, is installed on version 3.8.10. How do you manage this?

Comment: Possibly vs code is pointing to a different installation of Python or is using a different environment. Look deeper into Vs code settings.

Comment: Please post the solution in the answer space. Do not edit the question

Comment: Multiple versions of `pip` is covered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip

Comment: You can verify the specific python location listed in your workspace settings json (command palette ==> workspace settings json). Use this specific python to list your pip packages e.g. using `your-specific-python-3.10 -m pip list` - odf is likely not there, because you probably installed it for a different python...

Comment: (Accordingly, you can `your-specific-python-3.10 -m pip install odfpy` to install it, but best practice is to work with a python virtual environment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/ will make life much easier)

Answer (score 0):

Please check which pip you are using through the command of `pip --version`.

After you switch the python interpreter in the VSCode, please create a new terminal, and make sure it has activated the environment you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

I also use VS code and use Python 3.10 and i had try to download the odfpy which has gone alright, i use the command `python -m pip install odfpy`

try and see if it work for you though.

If it does not work, maybe try and create a virtual environment if you haven't created it yet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was getting same error while using import-export django module. Installing odf library didn't worked got same error. I resolve this issue by simply `pip install tablib==0.14.0`.