# No module named pip which using virtualenv-based python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When running the system-installed python, I can find pip:

```
% which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
% python3 --version
Python 3.9.7
% /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

However, if I create a virtualenv with this `python3` and activate it, then I can no longer find `pip`:

```
% which python3
~/venv/bin/python3
% ls -la `which python3`
~/venv/bin/python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3
% python3 -m pip --version
~/venv/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

I am completely baffled by this.

What is it about reading through a symlink that could make `pip` disappear?

Comment: `ls ~/venv/bin/` has pip in it? How about `which pip` after you have activated the virtualenv.

Comment: @Jay: You're right, no pip in `~/venv/bin/`. `which pip` fails after activating the virtualenv.

Comment: I thought `pip` came standard with virtualenvs; for instance on another platform I have access to `which pip` is found in the `venv`; moreover it is not a symlink to a system `pip`  . . .

Comment: Right, there should be a `pip` in the `venv/bin`. Secondly the `~/venv/bin/python3` should not be a symlink.. How did you create the `virtualenv`?
Try creating a fresh one, `virtualenv new_venv -p python3` and make sure that it has pip in `new_venv/bin` and `new_env/bin/python3` is not a symlink

Comment: The `python3` is a symlink to the system python3 on every platform I've tried . . ..

Comment: Virtualenv created with `python3 -m venv .`

Comment: I created a new venv from scratch. No `pip` is in `~/venv/bin` on the platform of interest; however it is on every other platform I've tried.

Comment: That's weird, what platform are you on? Try installing `virtualenv` using `pip install virtualenv` and then try creating one from there `virtualenv new_venv -p python3` and see if new_venv/bin has everything or not.

Comment: Platform is CentOS7.

Comment: Can't use `virtualenv` because that's python2 correct?

Comment: @Jay: Fixed it via `python3 -m virtualenv .`; looks like you were basically on the right track. Want to post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python's `venv` module introduced in python 3.3 is different from `virtualenv` and has a subset of `virtualenv`'s features.

From https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

> The `venv` module does not offer all features of this library, to name
> just a few more prominent:
>
> - is slower (by not having the app-data seed method)
> - is not as extendable, cannot create virtual environments for    arbitrarily installed python versions (and automatically discover
>   these),
> - is not upgrade-able via pip,
> - does not have as rich programmatic API (describe virtual environments    without creating them).

So an environment created using `venv` does not have a separate `pip` installed so I would recommend using `virtualenv` instead.

You can install the `virtualenv` module by running

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

Create a new `virtualenv` in the current directory -

```
python3 -m virtualenv .
```

or you can also use

```
virtualenv env_name -p python3
```

Comment: [Why venv is preferred over virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe/47559925#47559925)