# What is the difference between a virtual environment and a virtual envelope?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Can someone please explain the difference (if any) between a "virtual environment" and a "virtual envelope", within the context of the various Python virtual environment managers?

Comment: Where have you seen "virtual envelope"? To me it looks like a misunderstanding of for what "env" is an abbreviation.

Comment: It seems to me that "envelope" is just a wrong expansion of the "env".

Comment: The only place the term is used is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923461/7976758). Most certainly it's a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I can see only three real references to "virtual envelope" using google and two of them appear to potentially be autocomplete issues.

The only reference I see that repeatedly uses this term is from this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923461/218663

that uses it numerous times to describe what otherwise would be called a "virtual environment".

So:

> There is either no difference between "virtual environment" and
> "virtual envelope" as they are synonyms or better yet, there just
> really is no common term "virtual envelope" and when you see it, the
> author meant to type "virtual environment".