# How to create a virtualenv in python using cmd

Tags: python, cmd, virtualenv

I am using this command:

```
python -m virtualenv venv
```

and this is what comes out:

> C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: No module named virtualenv`

Comment: The name of the module is `venv`, not `virtualenv`. So the command should be `python -m venv venv`

Comment: I think this answer provides a detailed explanation of virtual environments in python. You will understand virtualenv and venv: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41573588/1836069

Answer (score 1):

as Serge mentioned in the comments, your command is incorrect. Instead it should be:
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment

see this for more info https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python3 or Python2?

If Python2, use the `virtualenv` command. You'll first need to install e.g.  `py -m pip install --user virtualenv`. Then you can create the environment: `py -m virtualenv myenv` (where 'myenv' can be any name you want to call the environment). Then you can activate it using: `source myenv/bin/activate`.

If you are using Python3, use the `venv` command instead. I'm not a Windows user, but I don't think you have to install if using Python3, so you can go straight to creating the environment).
Create the environment using:
`py -m venv myenv` (again, 'myenv' can be renamed).
Then you activate the environment in the same way as above (`source myenv/bin/activate`).

This Python documentation (https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) explains in detail.