# Installing OpenCV From Conda Environment YML File

Tags: python, opencv, conda

I'm trying out OpenCV with Python bindings for which I'm using the following YML file:

```
name: opencv-python-sandbox
channels:
  - menpo
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - jupyter=1.0.0
  - jupyterlab=0.34.9
  - keras=2.9.0
  - matplotlib=3.5.2
  - numpy=1.23.1
  - opencv-python==4.6.0.66
  - pandas=1.4.3
  - python=3.8.0
  - scikit-learn=1.1.1
  - scipy=1.8.1
  - tensorboard=2.9.1
  - tensorflow=2.9.1
```

When I rain it threw some errors and says that it is not able to resolve OpenCV and Tensorflow:

```
(ml-sandbox) joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/Private/ml-projects/ml-sandbox/opencv-python-sandbox$ conda env create -f environment.yml 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - tensorflow=2.9.1
  - opencv-python==4.6.0.66
```

How to get this fixed? Do I need to add pip to my environment.yml and then manually install opencv via pip after activating the conda environment?

Comment: use the **official** package, hosted on PyPI, installable using `pip`: `opencv-contrib-python` or `opencv-python`. both contain all the base modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fixed it yourself by moving the requirements to the pip section, which results in an installation from Pypi. I just wanted to add explanation why your original attempt did not work and suggestions in case you want to strictly stick to using `conda`. Note that for both `tensorflow` and `opencv`, the packages provided on `conda-forge` are not maintained by the respective developers, often resulting in them lacking behind in versions.

The python bindings for openCV are called `py-opencv` on `conda forge` and have different version strings, so you would need to put `py-opencv==4.6.0` in your yml

[tensorflow on conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) goes only up to 2.8.1. So when strictly sticking to conda, you would need to downgrade the version

You can always check available versions for packages by using `conda search -c <channel> <package-name>` from your terminal

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this was not answered by anyone else as this seems to be a very common problem. Nevertheless, I was able to solve this by adding **pip** as a dependency in my environment.yml and **use pip to install OpenCV** and any other libraries that won't resolve with Conda.

My environment.yml looks like this:

```
name: ml-sandbox
channels:
  - menpo
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - jupyter=1.0.0
  - jupyterlab=0.34.9
  - keras=2.9.0
  - matplotlib=3.5.2
  - pandas=1.4.3
  - python=3.8.0
  - pip=22.1.2
  - scikit-learn=1.1.1
  - scipy=1.8.1
  - tensorboard=2.9.1
  - pip:
      - numpy==1.23.1
      - opencv-contrib-python==4.6.0.66
```

Comment: it's been 2-3 hours, which is very little time. OpenCV people aren't that many, and we tend to avoid anything involving anaconda/conda/conda-forge because that's more of a headache than simply installing the official package with pip.

Comment: Then how do you manage Python environments? How do you share them in a group of developers in a company?

Comment: [venv, virtualenv, ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe) Continuum didn't invent the ideas. -- usually I don't bother with any of that, beyond a `requirements.txt` that anyone can deal with by just passing it to pip. people are responsible for their own environments. I don't tell them what to use.