# Finding python on Apple Silicon

Tags: python, macos

I have installed Python on my Apple Silicon (ARM64) machine, but it installs it as `python3` and not `python`.

The problem is that I have a `node.js` project with dependencies which need python (and pip). They fail to build because they are unable to find `python`.

`python3` is on the path at `/opt/homebrew/python3` which in turn is a link to

`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/bin/python3`

I think I need to create a symbolic link `python` to `/opt/homebrew/python3`, but am unsure which path the use `/opt/homebrew/python` or `/Applications/python` or something else.

Or would it just be cleaner to create a virtualenv ?

Comment: Creating a virtual environment and running your `node.js` project from there is probably the simplest solution, as no matter what Python you use to create the virtual environment, it will be installed as `python` in the virtual environment's `bin` directory.

Comment: Some OS distributions do let you choose whether `python` will refer to a Python 2 or Python 3 installation, and someday Python 3 should become the default, but the recommendation to use virtual environments may delay that or make the point moot.

Comment: Have you considered creating aliases?

Comment: (Keep in mind that even if `python` *does* refer to a Python 3 version, it may not be the correct *minor* version that your project requires. Maybe it needs Python 3.11 and you haven't upgraded from Python 3.9 yet.)

Comment: @Fred Aliases are expanded by the shell; a reference to Python in a `node` script won't care about any shell aliases that have been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv might be able to solve your issue. Depending on the directory you are in, it will intelligently set your python version.

[Here's a diagram that explains how python environments work](https://xkcd.com/1987/)

Comment: I've gone for virtualenv, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Not quite, but if it solves your immediate issue then great!
`virtualenv` will isolate your python libraries. `pyenv` isolates your python versions. Here's a good write up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe.

I use a combination of pyenv and https://python-poetry.org.