# Activate venv - Complete newbie trying to figure out the basics of python virtual env

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm using chatgpt to talk me through setting up a virtual environment so I can run a script but I'm stumped on the cmd to activate the venv.
I enter:
it starts with C: \Users\Max>

I enter: cd "D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT\venv\Scripts"
and it responds with
C:\Users\Max>

which I then enter activate.bat
and it responds: 'activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I don't know what to do here, I can see there is an activate windows batch file in my Scripts location but my Command Prompt isn't finding it.

I'm sure this is a simple fix, any help?

I am expecting it to say:
(venv) C:\Users\Max\D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT\venv\Scripts>

Comment: okay so I worked on the PATH install by reinstalling Python but it still does not find a python version when I enter python --version... I'm at a loss at this point

Comment: You do not really need to activate the virtual environment. It can be convenient to do so, but for beginners I find it rather confusing. -- Instead you can call the executables present in the virtual environment's `Scripts` directory. So for example to install libraries in the virtual environment you could run something like the following: `"D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT\venv\Scripts\python" -m pip install NameOfLibrary`.

Comment: ChatGPT is _not intelligent_. Don't treat it like an expert. Treat it like an intern whose work is always questionable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Windows Command prompt, either within Windows Terminal or Command Console.
In order to change drives at the Command prompt, you either have to enter just the drive letter by itself `D:` followed by an approriate `cd` command, or include the `/D` option in your `cd` command.

Example:

```
C:\Users\Max>D:
D:\>cd "Python Projects\Translator GPT\"
D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT>
```

or

```
C:\Users\Max>cd /D "D:Python Projects\Translator GPT\"
D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT>
```

Once you're in the working directory for your project, call the activation script

```
D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT>venv\Scripts\activate.bat
(venv) D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT>
```

If you work in Powershell instead of Command Console, the `/D` option for the `cd` command is not required.  Then the activation script Activate.ps1 is called by using the `&` (call) command

```
PS C:\Users\Max\>cd "D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT"
PS D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT\> & venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(venv) PS D:\Python Projects\Translator GPT\>
```

You may want to look at [setting up VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) or another IDE for working with Python, as it can handle activating the venv for you automatically whenever you reopen the workspace.

Instead of using ChatGPT, I would suggest finding an actual tutorial for the version of Python you're running or [reading the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).  ChatGPT just gathers info from other sources and doesn't always put it back together into a correct answer - it just looks correct if you don't know enough to know why its wrong.

Some detailed discussion on the various virtual env options in Python:
[What is the difference between venv, pyvenv, pyenv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe)